# Visual Studio 2015 Community version

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2015, sdk

there is a problem.
I've instaled VS 2015 Community version. I wanted to open the project from another computer and there is a problem with it.

> Error: 
>   1. Could not find SDK "SQLite.WP81, Version=3.12.2".
>
> Warnings:
>    1. The referenced component 'SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1' could not be found.
>    2. Warning   IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed
>   project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.

What should I do to work on this project on this computer ? How can I download missing SDK ?

P.s. Im going to work on widnows Phone application.

Thx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is missing SQLite For Windows Phone 8.1 library. Download an updated version of SQLite.WP8.1 here https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b. 
 Install it and relaunch Visual Studio.
Further information, including complete documentation, may be found at the official web site "http://www.sqlite.org/".

Comment: Thanks m8! I'll check this and write the result :)

Comment: There is still problem with the same sdk. But the is no errors already.  previous error with sdk is warning now. (there is the same text: Could not find SDK "SQLite.WP81, Version=3.12.2". Should I load that sdk in visual studio ?

Comment: Uninstall any previous version and install this one into Visual Studio and now Restart VS, the problem might be from VS trying to upgrade to the latest version you downloaded.

Comment: Achhh... no way. There is still a problem
`Error: Could not find SDK "SQLite.WP81, Version=3.12.2". 
Warning:The referenced component 'SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1' could not be found.
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.Warning CS4014 Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.`

Comment: did you uninstall the previous version? did you restart vs? It looks like your project still has some references to the previous version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123296/discussion-between-mordziasty-and-frank-odoom).